# Can't install Twisted 17.1.0 on mac

Tags: python, macos, twisted

Trying to install Twisted on my compute(macOS Sierra 10.12.2). Python version is 2.7.10.

I try to install from pip like this `pip install Twisted` and failed with error

> IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '/tmp/easy_install-8eVovT/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-u0u1h9/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-5iVHg5/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-UZwSl2/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-9nRMC3/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-1bP8j6/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-E8B9b_/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-5zegl0/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-47Gzfa/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-rvfOEw/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-c08BDr/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-ZAyj8l/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-w3QowO/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-DoydBb/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-SsMoHm/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-_ZTPwM/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-opozZc/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-xY7XU8/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-1J5k5e/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-9SlyRn/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-87hrjt/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-20CF7n/Twisted-17.1.0/temp/easy_install-cxyH6n/Twisted-17.1.0/docs/core/examples/threadedselect/Cocoa/SimpleWebClient/English.lproj/MainMenu.nib/keyedobjects.nib

then I download the source code from http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads.

run command `python setup.py install` and I got the same error message.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried using Twisted 15.5.0 on macOS Sierra, and it works!
https://github.com/twisted/twisted/archive/twisted-15.5.0.zip

I also tried 16.x.x and 17.x.x and the error is the same.

Comment: I was able to install Twisted 17.9.0 on my machine.

Comment: I am not able to install today on Sierra 10.12. The install hangs after "Running command python setup.py egg_info" . Twisted 15 installs successfully but cannot be upgraded.